# Flutter size button

Tags: android, button, flutter

I'm making a `FlatButton` for sizes so the user is going to select his own size.
**how can I make the button border goes bold when the user presses the button?**

-the buttons are created by ListView.builder so I can't set local variables for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a variable which hold the button number who's border you want to set bolder and on click you can change value of that variable.

following example clear your idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldInputState createState() => _TextFieldInputState();
}

class _TextFieldInputState extends State<TextFieldInput> {
  final List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

  int number = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: (list.length).ceil(),
              itemBuilder: (context, int index){
                return new FlatButton(
                  key: Key(index.toString()),
                    child: new Text(list[index].toString()),
                    shape: Border.all(
                      width: number==index ? 5.0 : 3.0
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          number = index;
                        });
                    }
                );
              }
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```